# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre ambos códigos para que uno dé "segmentation fault" y el otro no?

Tags: c

Supongamos que tenemos este **primer código**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        char **campos;
        char *palabra;
        int i = 3;
        if(argc > 1){
                while(i > 0){
                        palabra = argv[i];
                        campos[i] = palabra;
                        printf("Éxito: %s\n",campos[i]);
                        i--;
                }
        }
        return 1;
}
```

El cual, al compilar, te avisa de que la variable "campos", lo mismo, se usa sin inicializar. Concretamente:

*prueba.c:10:10: warning: ‘campos’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
campos[i] = palabra;*

Al ejecutar, la primera iteración ya resulta en un *segmentation fault*.

Ahora supongamos el **segundo código**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        char **campos;
        char *palabra;
        palabra = "Hola Mundo";
        campos[0] = palabra;
        printf("%s\n",campos[0]);
}
```

En esta ocasión, salta una advertencia similar al compilar:

*prueba2.c:7:12: warning: ‘campos’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
campos[0] = palabra;*

Sin embargo, la ejecución sucede sin ningún problema.

Entonces, tenemos dos códigos: ambos siguen la misma idea (almacenar palabras en "campos"), pero el segundo solo tiene una iteración. La estructura de ambos códigos es también similar (quitando los bucles). Entonces, **¿por qué el primero no ejecuta y el segundo sí?**

Yo veo lo siguiente:

**(1)** campos[i] me devuelve un puntero char*.

**(2)** "palabra" es un puntero char*.

**(3)** Hacer *palabra = "Hola Mundo";* implica cambiar la dirección a la que apunta "palabra" hacia la dirección en la que se encuentra la letra 'H' del string "Hola Mundo". Así, "palabra" apunta a "Hola Mundo".

**(4)** Así pues, si hago *campos[i] = palabra* estoy haciendo *campos[i] = argv[i]*, lo que implica que el puntero char* que es campos[i] apunta a la misma dirección a la que apunta argv[i].

Entonces: ¿qué está pasando en estos códigos para que, a pesar de su similitud, uno ejecute y el otro no?

Gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

¿Qué diferencia hay? En principio ninguna.

Ambos códigos tienen un error de bulto y es que el puntero doble `campos` **no está inicializado**. Cualquier intento de acceder a cualquier posición de `campos` generará una situación indeterminada.

Las situaciones indeterminadas se caracterizan por no dejar claro cual debe ser el comportamiento del programa en ese caso. Esto quiere decir que dependiendo del compilador, del Sistema Operativo, del hardware ... en unos casos el programa se comportará de una forma y en otros de otra.

Aunque para ti las operaciones sean equivalentes, para el compilador no tienen por qué serlo.

Aquí tienes, por ejemplo, el ensamblado correspondiente al primer ejemplo [[enlace]](https://godbolt.org/z/nhadcosds):

```
.LC0:
    .string "\303\211xito: %s\n"
main:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 48
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-36], edi
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-48], rsi
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 3
    cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-36], 1
    jle     .L2
    jmp     .L3
.L4:
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    cdqe
    lea     rdx, [0+rax*8]
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-48]
    add     rax, rdx
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax]
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], rax
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    cdqe
    lea     rdx, [0+rax*8]
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
    add     rdx, rax
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
    mov     QWORD PTR [rdx], rax
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    cdqe
    lea     rdx, [0+rax*8]
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
    add     rax, rdx
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax]
    mov     rsi, rax
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    mov     eax, 0
    call    printf
    sub     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
.L3:
    cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
    jg      .L4
.L2:
    mov     eax, 1
    leave
    ret
```

Y, a continuación, el ensamblado del segundo código [[enlace]](https://godbolt.org/z/We6ajMGWc):

```
.LC0:
    .string "Hola Mundo"
main:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 16
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
    mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    mov     QWORD PTR [rax], rdx
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax]
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    puts
    mov     eax, 0
    leave
    ret
```

Verás como no eres capaz de encontrar una relación directa entre ambos códigos ... si bien es cierto que el código del segundo ejemplo se encuentra casi casi en el primer ejemplo ... pero se queda en un casi casi.

En cualquier caso, lo dicho, el origen del error está en que `campos` no está inicializado. Hay que reservar memoria para ese array:

```
char **campos = (char**)malloc(3 * sizeof(char*));
```

Una vez hecho eso ambos códigos deberían funcionar.

Answer (score 5):

Eso es [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido). Un programa con comportamiento indefinido puede funcionar, puede no funcionar, puede actuar de manera extraña o puede [invocar demonios en tus fosas nasales](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nasal_demon).

¿Por qué en un caso pasa X y en otro caso pasa Y? porque es comportamiento indefinido y podría haber pasado cualquier otra cosa.

---

Según el [estándar de C](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n2731.pdf) (la traducción y los resaltados son míos):

> #### 6.5.2.1 Indizado de formaciones
>
> Una expresión sufijo seguida de una expresión en paréntesis angulares `[]` es la designación de un indizado de una formación. **La definición del operador de indizado es tal que la expresión `E1[E2]` es idéntica a `(*((E1)+(E2)))`**. [ ... ]

> #### 6.5.6 Operadores de adición
>
> 9. Cuando una expresión que tiene un tipo entero es sumada o restada de un puntero, el resultado obtiene el tipo del operando puntero. [ ... ] **Si tanto el operando puntero como el resultado apuntan a elementos de la misma formación, o un elemento más allá del último elemento de la formación**, su evaluación no debe producir desbordamiento; sin embargo, **el comportamiento es indefinido**.

Comment: El otro dia vi un rickroll para ejemplificar el UB (que planeo usar como ejemplo
ahora). Es la primera vez que oigo de demonios nasales ...